# How to transform object into sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object, lodash

I want to transform this to an array of values ordered based on an array of keys:

```
{
  tom: 1,
  jim: 2,
  jay: 3
}
```

`Input` -> `Output` examples:

`['jim', 'tom', 'jay']` -> `[2, 1, 3]`

`['jay', 'tom', 'jim']` -> `[3, 1, 2]`

How can I accomplish this? I'd rather a one line lodash solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lodash's [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#at) to get an array of the values in the order that you want:

```js
var data  = {
  tom: 1,
  jim: 2,
  jay: 3
};

var result1 = _.at(data, ['jim', 'tom', 'jay']);
var result2 = _.at(data, ['jay', 'tom', 'jim']);

console.log("['jim', 'tom', 'jay'] -> ", JSON.stringify(result1));
console.log("['jay', 'tom', 'jim'] -> ", JSON.stringify(result2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could map the values with plain Javascript with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
var data = { tom: 1, jim: 2, jay: 3 },
    order = ['jim', 'tom', 'jay'],
    result = order.map(k => data[k]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = {
  tom: 1,
  jim: 2,
  jay: 3
}

const order = ['jay', 'tom', 'jim'];

const result = order.map((item) => data[item]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function SortByKeyArray(obj, key_arr) {
    return key_arr.map(k => obj[k]);
}
```

Or

```
let SortByKeyArray = (obj, keys) => keys.map(k => obj[k]);
```

Which is more friendly to me.